# Adding innerHTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

```
<div id="ones">
 <span class="dice">&#9856;</span>
 <p>-</p>
 </div>
```

I am accessing this **p** tag in inside **id=ones**. By this Javascript line.

```
var valueCount = 0;
    var valueCount = document.getElementById('ones').getElementsByTagName('p').textContent;
    valueCount++;
    document.getElementById('ones').getElementsByTagName('p').textContent = valueCount;
```

on the console, I am getting **NaN**. Where am I doing wrong???

Comment: `Get Elements By Tag Name`. Elements. You will get all P tags in an array, even if it's just one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `document.getElementById` for accessing `p` tag which doesn't have any `id` or `class` attribute.You can use `document.querySelector` but need a digit in the paragraph that can be converted to a number using for example parseInt

```js
const valueP = document.querySelector('#ones p');
var valueCount = parseInt(valueP.textContent);
valueCount++;
valueP.textContent = valueCount;
```

```html
<div id="ones">
  <span class="dice">&#9856;</span>
  <p>0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just editing my answer.You had done before that.Thank you so much.

Comment: This is also giving **NaN** value for **valueCount**. The HTML file cannot be edited it will be same `<p>-</p>` . It should be done without changing HTML.  This answer is the same as was mine.

Answer (score 0):

in code you provided we can see that you define `valueCount` as 0, then we take text data from p tag and assign this value to `valueCount` so now in `valueCount` we have '-' string, then we try to increment this incorrect value, so now `valueCount` is NaN, that's the issue

```
var valueCount = 0;
var valueCount = document.getElementById('ones').getElementsByTagName('p').textContent;
valueCount++;
document.getElementById('ones').getElementsByTagName('p').textContent = valueCount;
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#ones p")` is much shorter.

Comment: yeah, also in `getElementsByTagName('p').textContent` `textContent` is undefined, because `getElementsByTagName('p')` returns array, so yeah, `querySelector` is better in this case, you'll get first element from array of elements matched to selector